# AWS EC2: (Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Error:

> 2022/02/25 05:25:23 [error] 16292#16292: *1 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.9.17,
> server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.21.11.88"

It's my first time uploading a fullstack JAR file in AWS EC2. Jar file contains Thymleaf web pages and the main java codes.

I've also done setting my RDS in AWS as well.I changed the security group to 'allow access' anywhere so I can connect to it on my local MySQL Workbench. By this, Im done setting up my SQL tables.

So I uploaded the JAR file. The status went from Healthy to Severe.
When I access the URL of my app I get this:

[image]

**application.properties**

```
server.port=5000
```

**AWS Security Group**
[image]

**Inbound Rules**
[image]

**Health Monitoring**
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here's where Im at

[image]

Is this what's causing my errors?

Comment: You have to verify that your application works on port 5000

Comment: do you happen to know where I could specify this port 5000?

Comment: @Marcin yes, nothing helps.Im new to AWS and for me this is basic stuff and people on SO dont seem to know about it which is funny because this is beginner level.

Answer (score 0):

By default EB expects your app to listen on port 5000. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html):

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk configures the nginx proxy to forward requests to your application on port 5000. You can override the default port by setting the **PORT environment property** to the port on which your main application listens.

Comment: yeh I specifed my applicaiton.properties in springboot to use 
server.port=5000 , but still doesnt work . . pls refer to updated question

Comment: @JoonaRitva Then you have to verify that you application is actually working. SSH to the EB instance and `curl` from localhost.

Comment: how do i ' SSH to the EB instance and curl from localhost'

Comment: I was reading the docs, do I need an EC2 key pair?

Comment: @JoonaRitva You can connect use AWS console with web ssh client.